# Wordpress display Welcome message in header

Tags: php, wordpress, authentication

in my wordpress theme https://suonareaorecchio.com I have this line of code
in my Site specific plugin to display a login logout button in the header:

```
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items', 'add_login_logout_link', 10, 2);
    function add_login_logout_link($items, $args) {
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        $loginoutlink = wp_loginout('', false);
    } else {
        $loginoutlink = wp_loginout('', false);
    }
    $items .= '<li>'. $loginoutlink .'</li>';
    return $items;
}
```

It works perfectly. If user is not logged in it shows Login, otherwise Logout.
What I would like to accomplish is this.

If user is logged in, I'd like it to say "Hi user" (where user is the first name) and set a redirection to a specific page (let's say https:/mysite.com/profile).

The logout button will be a submenu of this and redirect to home page. If user is not logged in it just display a Login button as usual.

Any help?

Thank you so much!

Paolo

Answer (score 0):

i think you should to modify wp_loginout function by applying filters

```
add_filter('loginout','loginout_text_change');

function loginout_text_change($text) 
{
    $login_text_before = 'Log in';
    $login_text_after = 'Sign-In';

    $logout_text_before = 'Log out';
    $logout_text_after = 'Sign-Off';

    $text = str_replace($login_text_before, $login_text_after ,$text);
    $text = str_replace($logout_text_before, $logout_text_after ,$text);
    return $text;
}
```